# Disable notification if my webpage is not open in any tab

Tags: javascript, firebase, browser, push-notification

I want to disable notification if my website tab is closed. How can I achieve this?

Here is my code to show the firebase push notification.

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

//Code for show webpage background notification
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
   //Code for show notifications
});

//Code for show webpage foreground notification
messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
   //Code for show notifications
});
```

I want to show notifications only when the webpage is open. I have to disable notification if the webpage is not opened in any tab.

Help me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest to what you want is:

1. Detect when your page is unloaded

`window.addEventListener('unload', e => { ... })`

2. Unsubscribe through your push notification manager
   *Code from MDN and is not mine*

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(reg) {
  reg.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function(subscription) {
    subscription.unsubscribe().then(function(successful) {
      // You've successfully unsubscribed
    }).catch(function(e) {
      // Unsubscription failed
    })
  })
});
```

Note that this requires you to re-subscribe to your push service every time your page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, unload event is called on the refresh page and back button also. And in chrome, unload event only detects when the user clicks at any point in the window.

Comment: That's true, but AFAIK its the only way to detect if someone closes your page if you want to do it with ServiceWorkers, otherwise I think the method proposed by @Frank is the most practical.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to deliver the notifications while the page is open, consider using another delivery mechanism than FCM. I'd recommend having a look at something like the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database), which can be used without needing a service worker (since it only works while the page is open).

Answer (score 0):

In your service worker you can use the [clients service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/matchAll) to check for the number of windows that you have open and then choose whether or not to display a notification. Its worth noting that this would only work if you do **not** include the Notification payload in the messages that you are sending as they will be automatically handled and displayed.